# Нет вкладки Git в панели меню Webstorm

Tags: git, webstorm, jetbrains, create-react-app, yarn

Лобрый день. создал CRA через "yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript". Всё создалось, строка Happy Hacking появилась. Скрытая папка git тоже появилась.

Но, когда я открываю этот проект в Webstorm, у меня нет вкладки Git в панели меню.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А также неактивны кнопки запуска проекта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём причина?
Удаляю вручную папку git в и инициализирую заново. Не помогает.

При этом, если я создаю CRA черех "npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript",  то всё норм работает. Git вэбштормом подхватывается